# How to send a message right after an embed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to send the embed message first, and then it sends a message on the channel `"example: !embed hello"`

```
if(!args.length) return message.channel.send({embed: {
          color: 16777201,
          description: 'put a message to embed',
    },
  })
  .then((message) => message.delete({ timeout: 10000 }));
```

The same second you send the embed, send the message together, then in ten seconds the two messages will be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a content property to [`message.channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) as such:

```js
if(!args.length) return message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    color: 16777201,
    description: 'put a message to embed',
  },
  content: "example: !embed hello"
 })
   .then((message) => {
     message.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
   });
```

---

**Note that this will send the message along with the embed, being above the embed, I suggest adding to the embed directly**:

```js
if(!args.length) return message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    color: 16777201,
    description: 'put a message to embed',
    fields: [
      {
        "name": "Example",
        "value": "!embed hello"
      }
    ]
  }
 })
   .then((message) => {
     message.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
   });
```

---

If you insist on a direct answer the way you requested it, you can use:

```js
if(!args.length) return message.channel.send({
  embed: {
    color: 16777201,
    description: 'put a message to embed',
  }
 })
   .then((message) => {
     message.channel.send('example: !embed hello').then((msg) => {
       msg.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
     })
     message.delete({ timeout: 10000 });
   });
```

---

For more info:

- [Discord.js.org - Docs - `TextChannel#Send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)